# Dijkstra algorithm for finding shortest paths

Tags: java

I need help to write code on Dijkstra algorithm for finding shortest paths by using java, and use only this version given below :

**procedure Dijkstra(G, w, r, Parent[0:n-1], Dist)

for v← 0 to n-1 do

Dist[v] ← ∞

InTheTree[v] ← .false.

endfor

Parent[r] ←-1

Dist[r] ←0

for Stage ←1 to n-1 do

Select vertex u that minimises Dist[u] over all u such that InTheTree[u] = .false.

InTheTree[u] = .true.            // add u to T

for each vertex v such that uv ∈ E do             // update Dist[v] and

if .not. InTheTree[v]  then                // Parent[v] arrays

if Dist[u] ← w(uv) < Dist[v] then

Dist[v] = Dist[u] + w(uv)

Nearest[v] ←()

Parent[r] ← u

endif

endif

endfor

endfor

end Dijkstra**

.....................
Thanks

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the OP asks others to implement their pseudocode in Java.

Comment: Hope http://www.sanfoundry.com/java-program-find-shortest-path-between-two-vertices-using-dijkstras-algorithm/ this helps

Comment: Specific questions about parts of the implementation are more than welcome, but StackOverflow is not for giving out code, nor will that help you to learn/understand what is going on.

Answer (score 0):

ArgoList has an implementation I just googled :

```
import java.util.PriorityQueue;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;

class Vertex implements Comparable<Vertex>
{
public final String name;
public Edge[] adjacencies;
public double minDistance = Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY;
public Vertex previous;
public Vertex(String argName) { name = argName; }
public String toString() { return name; }
public int compareTo(Vertex other)
{
    return Double.compare(minDistance, other.minDistance);
}
}

class Edge
{
public final Vertex target;
public final double weight;
public Edge(Vertex argTarget, double argWeight)
{ target = argTarget; weight = argWeight; }
}

public class Dijkstra
{
public static void computePaths(Vertex source)
{
    source.minDistance = 0.;
    PriorityQueue<Vertex> vertexQueue = new PriorityQueue<Vertex>();
    vertexQueue.add(source);

while (!vertexQueue.isEmpty()) {
    Vertex u = vertexQueue.poll();

        // Visit each edge exiting u
        for (Edge e : u.adjacencies)
        {
            Vertex v = e.target;
            double weight = e.weight;
            double distanceThroughU = u.minDistance + weight;
    if (distanceThroughU < v.minDistance) {
        vertexQueue.remove(v);
        v.minDistance = distanceThroughU ;
        v.previous = u;
        vertexQueue.add(v);
    }
        }
    }
}

public static List<Vertex> getShortestPathTo(Vertex target)
{
    List<Vertex> path = new ArrayList<Vertex>();
    for (Vertex vertex = target; vertex != null; vertex = vertex.previous)
        path.add(vertex);
    Collections.reverse(path);
    return path;
}

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Vertex v0 = new Vertex("Redvile");
Vertex v1 = new Vertex("Blueville");
Vertex v2 = new Vertex("Greenville");
Vertex v3 = new Vertex("Orangeville");
Vertex v4 = new Vertex("Purpleville");

v0.adjacencies = new Edge[]{ new Edge(v1, 5),
                             new Edge(v2, 10),
                           new Edge(v3, 8) };
v1.adjacencies = new Edge[]{ new Edge(v0, 5),
                             new Edge(v2, 3),
                             new Edge(v4, 7) };
v2.adjacencies = new Edge[]{ new Edge(v0, 10),
                           new Edge(v1, 3) };
v3.adjacencies = new Edge[]{ new Edge(v0, 8),
                             new Edge(v4, 2) };
v4.adjacencies = new Edge[]{ new Edge(v1, 7),
                           new Edge(v3, 2) };
Vertex[] vertices = { v0, v1, v2, v3, v4 };
    computePaths(v0);
    for (Vertex v : vertices)
{
    System.out.println("Distance to " + v + ": " + v.minDistance);
    List<Vertex> path = getShortestPathTo(v);
    System.out.println("Path: " + path);
}
}
}
```